# Use Google as the OIDC provider without leaking client secret in kubernetes

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, google-oauth, openid-connect

We have a single kubernetes development cluster. We want to give every developer working on this development cluster a namespaced controlled access.

We wanted to authenticate it using Google as the OIDC provider which kubernetes API supports.

But this required **client-secret** to be part of `~/.kube/config`

```
users:
- name: you@yourdomain.com
  user:
    auth-provider:
      name: oidc      
      config:
        client-id: <client-id>
        client-secret: <client-secret>
        idp-issuer-url: https://accounts.google.com        
        id-token: <id-token>
        refresh-token: <refresh-token>
```

We do not want to leak client secret to the user, since when the developer leaves the organization, the client secret will get leaked and can be misused to impersonate.

Please suggest how to authenticate the user in the kubernetes cluster using google as the OIDC provider and without leaking the client secret.

Comment: It seems strange for me, we have Google Cloud authentication in GKE using GSuite Organization. So even if person leaves organization but still has access token - it will be useless if this person is removed from organization in GSuite. And how you manage group membership with Google as OIDC?

Comment: Client secret can be misused by other malicious apps. Problem is even if the member leaves the org, any other app can use the client secret and now act as the current app as it has client id and secret both and can gain access by making existing user sign in to this app. More information on why client secret should not be leaked could be read here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14009/whats-the-benefit-of-the-client-secret-in-oauth2

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37822#issuecomment-264198821

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836757/can-google-client-id-and-client-secret-credential-be-exploited-by-a-non-org-memb create a new topic for client secret exploitation discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**Client_secret** is now optional for the k8s oidc config, which means that it can support public clients (with or without client_secret) and confidential clients (with client_secret, per kubectl user).

This mean that you don't need to use client secret to authentication but as I wrote in answer for your next question [`openid-kubernetes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836757/can-google-client-id-and-client-secret-credential-be-exploited-by-a-non-org-memb) there is no need to concern about leaking credentials.